# Why isn't my UIView resizing properly inside my UIViewController's subview?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that contains a subview and a UIToolbar. I'm trying to add another UIViewController containing an MKMapView as a subview, but it is not resizing properly and as a result, the map is overlapping the toolbar. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    [DebugLogger writeLog:@"Initializing RootViewController"];
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Root View";

        switchableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        switchableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        switchableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [DebugLogger writeLog:@"Calling viewDidLoad in RootViewController"];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView = [[[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [self.mapView.view setFrame:switchableView.frame];

    [switchableView addSubview:self.mapView.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

`switchableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;`

try this:

`switchableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Also, try setting mapView.view's autoresizingMask to the same thing.